# Linear Regression with Gradient Descent

Tags: java, machine-learning

I have written the following Java program to implement Linear Regression with Gradient Descent. The code executes but the result is not accurate. The predicted value of y is not the close to the actual value of y. For example, when x = 75 the expected y = 208 but the output is y = 193.784.

```
class LinReg {

    double theta0, theta1;

    void buildModel(double[] x, double[] y) {
        double x_avg, y_avg, x_sum = 0.0, y_sum = 0.0;
        double xy_sum = 0.0, xx_sum = 0.0;
        int n = x.length, i;
        for( i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
            x_sum += x[i];
            y_sum += y[i];
        }
        x_avg = x_sum/n;
        y_avg = y_sum/n;

        for( i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            xx_sum += (x[i] - x_avg) * (x[i] - x_avg);
            xy_sum += (x[i] - x_avg) * (y[i] - y_avg);
        }
        theta1 = xy_sum/xx_sum;
        theta0 = y_avg - (theta1 * x_avg);
        System.out.println(theta0);
        System.out.println(theta1);

        gradientDescent(x, y, 0.1, 1500);
    }

    void gradientDescent(double x[], double y[], double alpha, int maxIter) {
        double oldtheta0, oldtheta1;
        oldtheta0 = 0.0;
        oldtheta1 = 0.0;
        int n = x.length;
        for(int i = 0; i < maxIter; i++) {
            if(hasConverged(oldtheta0, theta0) && hasConverged(oldtheta1, theta1))
                break;
            oldtheta0 = theta0;
            oldtheta1 = theta1;
            theta0 = oldtheta0 - (alpha * (summ0(x, y, oldtheta0, oldtheta1)/(double)n));
            theta1 = oldtheta1 - (alpha * (summ1(x, y, oldtheta0, oldtheta1)/(double)n));
            System.out.println(theta0);
            System.out.println(theta1);


        }
    }

    double summ0(double x[], double y[], double theta0, double theta1) {
        double sum = 0.0;
        int n = x.length, i;
        for( i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
            sum += (hypothesis(theta0, theta1, x[i]) - y[i]);
        }
        return sum;
    }

    double summ1(double x[], double y[], double theta0, double theta1) {
        double sum = 0.0;
        int n = x.length, i;
        for( i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
            sum += (((hypothesis(theta0, theta1, x[i]) - y[i]))*x[i]);
        }
        return sum;
    }

    boolean hasConverged(double oldTheta, double newTheta) {
        return ((newTheta - oldTheta) < (double)0);
    }

    double predict(double x) {
        return hypothesis(theta0, theta1, x);
    }

    double hypothesis(double thta0, double thta1, double x) {
        return (thta0 + thta1 * x);
    }
}

public class LinearRegression {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Height data
        double x[] = {63.0, 64.0, 66.0, 69.0, 69.0, 71.0, 71.0, 72.0, 73.0, 75.0};
        //Weight data
        double y[] = {127.0, 121.0, 142.0, 157.0, 162.0, 156.0, 169.0, 165.0, 181.0, 208.0};
        LinReg model = new LinReg();
        model.buildModel(x, y);
        System.out.println("----------------------");
        System.out.println(model.theta0);
        System.out.println(model.theta1);
        System.out.println(model.predict(75.0));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing is wrong.

I verified the solution in R:

```
x <- c(63.0, 64.0, 66.0, 69.0, 69.0, 71.0, 71.0, 72.0, 73.0, 75.0)
y <- c(127.0, 121.0, 142.0, 157.0, 162.0, 156.0, 169.0, 165.0, 181.0, 208.0)

mod <- lm(y~x)
summary(mod)
```

> ```
> Call:
> lm(formula = y ~ x)
>
> Residuals:
>      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
> -13.2339  -4.0804  -0.0963   4.6445  14.2158 
>
> Coefficients:
>              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
> (Intercept) -266.5344    51.0320  -5.223    8e-04 ***
> x              6.1376     0.7353   8.347 3.21e-05 ***
> ---
> Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
>
> Residual standard error: 8.641 on 8 degrees of freedom
> Multiple R-squared:  0.897,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.8841 
> F-statistic: 69.67 on 1 and 8 DF,  p-value: 3.214e-05
> ```

Calculated y-hat for a X value of 75:

```
-266.5344 +(6.1376 *75)
```

> [1] 193.784

It's a correct prediction. I think the confusion must be around how regression works. Regression does not tell you the precise actual value of a data point in your training data corresponding to a given independent data point. That would just be a dictionary, not a statistical model (and in that case it wouldn't be able to interpolate or extrapolate).

Regression fits a least squares line to your data to estimate a model equation, which is then used to predict the dependent variable's value given independent variable values. The only case when this precisely predicts a data point in your training data is when you've overfit your model (which is bad).

For further information and links:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis

Comment: Yes I was confused with the concept of regression and gradient descent. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @noober Happy to help. If you want a good Java library for ML and regression I recommend Weka by the way.